# Ways to construct an ornamet from dif. color beads (graph theory algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, graph-theory

There are N colors of beads. You have bi beads of the ith color. You want to make an ornament by joining all the beads together. You create the ornament by using the following algorithm:

Step #1 Arrange all the beads in any order such that beads of the same color are placed together.

Step #2 The ornament initially consists of only the first bead from the arrangement.

Step #3 For each subsequent bead in order, join it to a bead of the same color in the ornament. If there is no bead of the same color, it can be joined to any bead in the ornament.

All beads are distinct, even if they have the same color. How many different ornaments can be formed by following the above algorithm? Two ornaments are considered different if two beads are joined by a thread in one configuration, but not in the other.

clarification

Think of the bead formation as a tree and not as a straight line. Any number of beads can be connected to a bead.

This problem is driving me crazy! I am told you must use Cayleys algorithm to get all the ways to build a tree for each of the beads of color ci and then you must join the trees together. Supposedly there is this formula for joining components into a tree, (s1s2. .. sk) × nk - 2, but I am not sure if I have the formula right nor am I convinced. Is anybody familiar with this formula and or can help me with this problem. Thanks guys. Oh by the way this is the algorithm I have so far. It is working on a few test cases but fails also.

public class BeadOrnament {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    int T, N;

    T = stdin.nextInt();

    while (T-- > 0) {

        N = stdin.nextInt();

        double[] colors = new double[N];
        double[] trees = new double[N];

        long ornaments = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            colors[i] = stdin.nextInt();
        }

        long t = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            trees[i] = Math.max(Math.pow(colors[i], colors[i] - 2), 1);
            t *= trees[i];
        }

        long s = 1;

        if (N > 1) {

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                s *= colors[i];
            }

            s *= Math.max(Math.pow(N, colors.length - 2), 1);

        }

        ornaments = s * t;

        System.out.println(ornaments);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: if anybody is familiar with that formula for ways of joining components into a tree is it (s1s2...sk) * NK -2, or (s1s2...sk)*n^(k-2)

Comment: please somebody help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to be careful of when using exponential functions and a lot of multiplications is overflow. Doubles are loosing precision if you go above 2<sup>52</sup>. This limit is exceeded already at 16 beads.

Consider using Java's [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead. Cayleys formula then becomes:

```java
BigInteger numberOfOrnaments(int beadCount) {
    if (beadCount <= 2) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    return BigInteger.valueOf(beadCount).pow(beadCount-2);
}
```

I couldn't find any formula for joining the ornaments (spanning trees) together. Your code should be correct for `N <= 2` at least, since you only add one string. For `N > 2` I can't say if it will work or not.

My intuition is that, you can join two trees by connecting any two beads (one from each tree) together. For bead-counts `n1` and `n2` respectivly, this can be done in `n1*n2` ways. The third tree you can connect to any of the two other trees, but you could also connect both of them to the third tree, without first joining them. The formula quickly gets very complicated.

---

Ah. Now I see. The complicated formula I was thinking of, for joining the ornaments, simplifies to `n1*n2*n3*...*nk*(n1+n2+n3+...+nk)^(k-2)`, where each `ni` is the bead-count for color `i`.

```java
BigInteger totalNumberOfConfigurations(int[] beadCounts) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int n : beadCounts) {
        result = result.multiply(numberOfOrnaments(n))
        result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(n));
        sum += n;
    }
    BigInteger x = BigInteger.valueOf(sum).pow(beadCounts.length - 2);
    result = result.multiply(x);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hey I appreciate you taking a a look thanks alot. The constraint on the number of beads for a certain color is 30 so I guess I should use ure idea with big integer. Yes i can see too that for joining two trees its s1*s2 because we choose a vertice from the first and the second . Does the formula i mentioned make sense to you in the general case at all?

Comment: and yes u r exactly right for n <=2 it is working but for anything greater is where I am failing. So the problem is in joinging all the components together into one big tree. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The `n` in your formula is not the number of *colors*, but the number of *beads*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final answer. Big thanks to Markus Jarderot. Just before your post I had tried what you gave as the correct formula but my implementation had an error , wrong variable usage (stupid mistake). Thanks again.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BeadOrnament {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        int T, N;

        T = stdin.nextInt();

        while (T-- > 0) {

            N = stdin.nextInt();

            int[] colors = new int[N];
            BigInteger[] trees = new BigInteger[N];

            BigInteger ornaments;

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                colors[i] = stdin.nextInt();
            }

            BigInteger t = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                trees[i] = numberOfTrees(colors[i]);
                t = t.multiply(trees[i]);
            }

            BigInteger sp = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
            BigInteger ss = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
            BigInteger tot = BigInteger.valueOf(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                sp = sp.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(colors[i]));
                ss = ss.add(BigInteger.valueOf(colors[i]));
            }

            if (N > 2) {
                ss = ss.pow(colors.length - 2);
                ss = ss.multiply(sp);
                tot = ss;
                ornaments = tot.multiply(t);
            } else if (N == 2) {
                tot = sp;
                ornaments = tot.multiply(t);
            } else {
                ornaments = t;
            }

            System.out.println(ornaments.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(1000000007)));
        }
    }

    public static BigInteger numberOfTrees(int beadCount) {
        if (beadCount <= 2) {
            return BigInteger.ONE;
        }
        return BigInteger.valueOf(beadCount).pow(beadCount - 2);
    }
}
```